# Style React components with `css` attribute

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I know that must be the way, where it possible to avoid overwriting any component (DOM node) styles with only inline styles (via `style` attribute), but instead make it much more readable and clean via `css` attribute. For example:

```
<StyledInput 
  css="width: 300px; border: 2px solid red"
  value={state.value}
  onChange={...}
  ...
/>
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any references for this solution. It may be related to Styled Components.

Comment: This is a emotion prop injected into every compoent. HEre is the [Link}(https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop)

Comment: @Sergey Lk - Is this StyledInput a customer React component that you created? and you want to pass the css props to it from the parent component?

Comment: @Subha yes, that it

Comment: @SergeyLk can you please share the code of StyledInput component

Answer (score 0):

You may use third-party npm package **[transform-css-to-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transform-css-to-js)**

**In the terminal**

```
npm i transform-css-to-js
```

**In your Parent file**

```
<StyledInput 
  css=`width: 300px; border: 2px solid red`
  value={state.value}
  onChange={...}
  ...
/>
```

Note: Here is used `backticks` instead of `string`

**In your StyledInput file**

```
import cssToJS from "transform-css-to-js";
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';
//other imports here

const StyledInput = (props)=> {
  const transformedCSS = cssToJS(props.css, true);
  return (
    <TextInput {...transformedCSS} />
  )
};
```

Note: Here I am assuming you want to use css styles in your TextInput and not in a View or some other tags. **Please remember TextInput only takes a limited number of styling options as props**. [RN Official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#view-props) have the list of allowed props. In case you want to use it in a View then just spread it like so

```
<View style={{...transformedCSS}}>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

The prop 'style' is already readable and is standard across all component libraries. Why would you want to go back to css?

To me personally, this is the cleanest way.

```
<StyledInput 
  style= {{width: 300; border: `2px solid red`}}
  value={state.value}
  onChange={...}
  ...
/>
```